# Check balance of ERC20 token in Hardhat using Ethers.js

Tags: ethereum, erc20, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm writing unit tests using Hardhat's mainnet fork, and for a test I want to check the `owner` account's initial balance of an ERC20 token, in particular DAI. Here's my test so far:

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Simple Test", function () {
    it("Check balance of DAI", async function () {
        const provider = ethers.provider;
        const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

        // Want to get initial DAI balance here so it can be compared later
    });
});
```

What's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. First thing I did was save the DAI contract address at the top:

```
const DAI_ADDRESS = "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f";
```

Then I had to use the [ERC20 token ABI](https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/), which I placed in the same folder as my test:

```
const ERC20ABI = require('./ERC20.json');
```

Then to get the `owner` account's DAI balance I just called `balanceOf()` from the DAI contract:

```
const DAI = new ethers.Contract(DAI_ADDRESS, ERC20ABI, provider);
DAIBalance = await DAI.balanceOf(owner.address);
```

This should work for any ERC20 token as well.